# Does publishing an embedded component publish all pages that use it?

Tags: cme

If I update a component that is used in many pages do I need to manually publish all the pages that are associated with the updated component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Publishing a component that is used on many pages will (re)publish every page that uses it. You can verify this by clicking on "Show items to publish" on the "Publish" dialog.

The (re) in (re)publish is extremely important - if the page was not published before, publishing this component will not publish the page.

Comment: +1. I have a post with [pictures for this (re)publishing scenario](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/10/lets-play-what-published-that-aka-sdl.html) to make this visual.